# WooCommerce Product Page css

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm new to Wordpress/WooCommerce and I'm trying to do something I thought would have been simple.

The very basic WooCommerce Single Product page has the Product Attributes, they all appear under one big column.

[image: new]

Where can I actually modify the style and css for Product Page, so that I can have them in 2 (or more) columns instead of one big row?

I see the table is itself is generated under class "woocommerce-product-attributes" and "shop_attributes" ?

Answer (score 1):

You've actually done most of the work finding this by identifying the classes (good job!). All you then had to do was to grep the WooCommerce code for those two - and you'll find them both in [templates/single-product/product-attributes.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.5.2/templates/single-product/product-attributes.php#L26).

So all you need to do to restructure the table is to override the single-product/product-attributes.php template and build the table as you'd like. You'll need to add this to your theme, or make a child theme, and include the modified version there. From the WooCommerce docs:

- [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme - How to edit files](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/#section-1)
- [Declaring WooCommerce support in themes](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Declaring-WooCommerce-support-in-themes)

(I don't think it's possible to restructure the table by CSS alone, since this is an HTML table with one TR per attribute - I think you'll have to change the HTML. But I may be wrong.)